# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 with OpenSSL library

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, openssl

I'm having issues using OpenSSL compiled as a Universal Library in an iOS project.

The following is what I have done:

1. I built a Universal framework (Object-C) for the targetting i386, armv7,armv7s, x86_64 and arm64.
2. I linked OpenSSL into this framework.
3. I used c++ to write some functions that use the OpenSSL library. It compiled successfully, and produced the final framework.
4. I used the command "file framework" and it confirms the framework actually contains code for i386, armv7, x86_64 and arm64 architectures. But, when I compile this, I get the following warning:

> ld: warning:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.1.sdk/usr/lib/libstdc++.dylib,
>   ignoring unexpected dylib file

5. I try to test the framework, but all of these C++ functions have a error message as following:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 .... ld: symbol(s) not found
>   for architecture x86_64.

When I use Xcode 4.X, it works OK (no for X86_64), but I use Xcode 7.1 now and have this trouble...

Can anybody give me some suggestion to solve it?

Comment: what exact commands did you enter to build and install the library?

Comment: First thing to do is run lipo -info against the fat lib you generated. This will list the targets actually compiled into it. If you used an xcode project to build openSSL, it's very easy to mess this up, by either not entering all of the target architectures in the right build setting, or by forgetting to turn off the "Build Active Architecture Only" option.

Comment: Use an established build script to do this properly for you: https://github.com/x2on/OpenSSL-for-iPhone

Comment: @TechnikEmpire . After I lipo -info , it shows "i386, x86_64, armv7, arm64". and  "Build Active Architecture Only"  have been set "NO"

Comment: @RichardHodges, in order to Clarify the issue, I write a simple C++  code(hpp,cpp), and try to call the simple function and it has the same problem~

Comment: the following is the sample C++ code I used to clarify the issue 
<code> 
//In test.hpp 
#ifndef test_hpp #define test_hpp #include <stdio.h> #end if void hello(); //in test.cpp #include "test.hpp" void hello(){ printf("hello"); } After xcode build, it still shows ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Comment: @Yung-Yi Can you post your code example as an edit to your question? Posting code in comments is messy and will reduce the quality of the original question. Also, please post the entire error code, because you're not saying what symbols are not found.

Comment: thanks for everyone's response，I solve the Problem by move the implement code(CPP) to header file (hpp). and Use  [link](github.com/x2on/OpenSSL-for-iPhone – Technik Empire) Openssl framework. 
Although, I don't know why XCode can't seperate CPP and HPP file. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Yung-Yi maybe your CPP sources are not being included in your project correctly. I had the exact same issue recently and when I went back and checked over my xcode project for the library, I found that the sources were listed in the project files view, but a couple of them had not actually been included as sources to compile under the project settings. Since you solved the issue, consider posting a detailed answer of how you solved it. Welcome to SO.

Comment: @TechnikEmpire, thanks for your response. In my condition, I just combine the source code(CPP) to header file(Hpp), and the problem solved, so what is the actual problem, I still can't known.

Comment: @Yung-Yi you moved your implementation from the source file (cpp) into the header file (hpp), that's a solution, but doesn't say why it's a solution. I believe from this we can conclude that your cpp file(s) were not properly included in the project for compilation.